# Extracting area with a range of lat long?

Tags: openstreetmap, data, visualisation, geolocation

Is there any online tool to extract a certain area with a range of lat long? I'd like to overlay some locations on a map. To do so, I need a map whose range is specified so that I can determine the locations.

I found [openStreetMap does it](http://www.openstreetmap.org/export#map=5/47.828/7.668&layers=H) but it's got some extra information on a map, including streets, shops and so on. For now, I need only country boundaries and names of country in Europe. Is this that hard to do this simple thing? Could you help?

Comment: So are we talking about areas of a rastered map or pure vector geodata?

Comment: Please clarify how you plan to determine your locations. In any GIS software (e.g. QGIS, ArcGIS...), you can add georeference background information and custom locations with the desired extent.

Comment: @Mapper I'm new to this field and don't know much about. a rasterised map is fine as long as I can determine a range of lat/long of the map.

Comment: @radouxju I'm planing to use Processing Language for this. with map() of it, you can determine a location according to lat/long and pixel size of an image of a map.

sounds like you are explaining a some common way to place objects on a map. I have no idea about GIS software. Are they useful to extract map of a certain range? are they free to use?

Answer (score 1):

So what you are looking for ways to get OSM maps:

- [static Maps](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Static_map_images) are services that can be called using a boundingbox (lat/lon pairs) and return an rendered/stitched raster image
- [WMS](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/WMS#OSM_WMS_Servers) / [TMS](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/TMS) is a common service protocol to get certain areas of maps as raster images (or tiles of it). This can be used with Desktop GIS (e.g [QGIS](http://qgis.org/), [OpenJUMP](http://www.openjump.org), ...) or [Webmap components](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Frameworks#Webmaps) for interactive browsing
- raw OSM geodata can be downloaded e.g. using [OverpassAPI](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) or [as dumps](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm). You need to render it on your own, but there are existing desktop solutions as [Maperitive](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Maperitive) or [TileMill](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/TileMill), ... . So you can tune your own style, but also need to put more work on that.

AFAIK ITO uses processing to create [their video animations](http://vimeo.com/2598878) out of OSM geodata (here with time-dimension), but the tool seems to be closed source.